# How do I put several tablenotes into one cell?

Tags: threeparttable, threeparttablex

I have been trying to put a table together. Since it is going to become a long one, I use the longtable here, but the problem is the same for a shorter one.

I want to add some remarks to certain lines in the table, for which I use the `ThreePartTable` environment provided by the `threeparttablex`-package. Now the problem is the tablenotes themselves are printed directly after the text without taking up space on their own, which is normally great, as it doesn't shift the alignment. But If I need two remarks for the same cell, both letters are being print on top of each other. There is an awful workaround using superscript and adding space manually, but it doesn't look nice at all. My question now is: is it possible to do it in a better way?

MWE for both cases follow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}
        \item[a] Reaction was performed according to GP1
        \item[b] Reaction was performed according to GP2
        \item[c] Alkynol XX was used
    \end{TableNotes}

    \begin{longtable}{ccc}
        \caption{table without workaround}\\    
        \toprule
        reagent & additive & temperature\\
        \midrule \endfirsthead
        %
        reagent & additive & temperature\\ 
        \midrule \endhead
        %   
        \bottomrule
        \insertTableNotes\\
        \endlastfoot
        %       
        reagent1\tnote{a} & --- & r.t.\\
        reagent2\tnote{b} & --- & cold\\
        reagent3\tnote{b}\tnote{c} & stuff, which didn't work & warm\\
    \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}
        \item[a] Reaction was performed according to GP1
        \item[b] Reaction was performed according to GP2
        \item[c] Alkynol XX was used
    \end{TableNotes}

    \begin{longtable}{ccc}
        \caption{Table with manual space and comma}\\   
        \toprule
        reagent & additive & temperature\\
        \midrule \endfirsthead
        %
        reagent & additive & temperature\\ 
        \midrule \endhead
        %   
        \bottomrule
        \insertTableNotes\\
        \endlastfoot
        %       
        reagent1\tnote{a} & --- & r.t.\\
        reagent2\tnote{b} & --- & cold\\
        reagent3\tnote{b}\ $^,$\tnote{c} & stuff, which didn't work & warm\\
    \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since numbering of the tablenotes is done manually anyways, why not just use `\tnote{b,c}`?

Comment: for the firswt case: `reagent3\tnote{b} \,\tnote{c}` (note space between `\tnot`)

Comment: The first solution works, no idea, why I didn't come up with this myself, seems so obvious. Thx for both your comments, I will put it up as an answer, so this question can be closed.